# Why mathematica is importing -3.46422 E - 16 as 25.4167?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am writing a code for extracting the fill factor, and while doing so, I realized that some of the data points were way off the list. It was importing any number like 4.25E-16 or -3.46422E-17 range as something else. Can anyone help me figure out the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: " It was importing any number like 4.25E-16 or -3.46422E-17 range as something else" --> and what was that _else_?

Comment: `E` in Mathematica is Euler's number 2.718..., more usually called *e*.  So it's parsing as -3.46422 multiplied by `E`, then subtract 16.  And that equals -25.4167 (perhaps you dropped the minus sign).

Comment: @NateEldredge Perhaps this is what is happening. It makes sense to me now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With data imported as strings

```
import = ReadList["example.dat", String]
```

> {"4.25E-16", "-3.46422E-17"}

```
convert[num_String] := ToExpression[StringReplace[num, "E" -> "*10^"]]

SetAttributes[convert, Listable]

numbers = convert[import]
```

> {4.25x10^-16, -3.46422x10^-17}

`Import` will do the conversion automatically

```
Import["example.dat"]
```

> {{4.25x10^-16}, {-3.46422x10^-17}}

while `ReadList` on its own will not

```
ReadList["example.dat"]
```

> {-4.4473, -26.4167}

Comment: Or `Read[StringToStream[#], Number] & /@ {"4.25E-16", "-3.46422E-17"}`